# Variables in Flask that are global are returning not defined

Tags: python, flask

Hello guys so I do have this part of a script:

```
global auth, username, password, index, authType, rotation # Frist try - doesn't work
auth, username, password, index, authType, rotation = None # Second try - doesn't work either


        
@app.route("/set", methods=["GET","POST"])
def setup():
    auth = request.args.get("auth", type=str)
    username = request.args.get("username", type=str)
    password = request.args.get("password", type=str)
    index = request.args.get("index")
    authType = request.args.get("type", type=str)
    rotation = request.args.get("rotation", type=str)
    
    print(authType)

    return anotherMethod()

def anotherMethod():
    #Do something here with authThype mentioned above.
    return "succes"
```

In this case, authType get's an error as not defined. Also, I have tried to set all the variables above to "None" and I have removed "global" declaration because I wanted to get them in one request and then process them into other methods without sending them as method variables but none of these methods worked.

Do you guys have a good ideea about how to be able to work with the variables sent through the api call into other methods of the same .py file ?

Comment: Is it "not defined", or is it `None`? The above code should either set it as the request arg or `None`

Comment: I have run your provided code and it does not raise an error for `authType` not defined, but just prints `None` as expected. Can you provide an example that reproduces your problem? Also see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GAEfan it’s sent via API call and when sent as the code above it gives an error as saying that authType is not defined. I have tried also to declare them as “None” instead of global but that didn’t worked either

Comment: @syntonym I have edited

Comment: Making variables `global` is rarely the best way to have data persist across multiple calls.  In this case as soon as you want more than 1 username/password, this will fail.

Comment: @noslenkwah as you haven't read. This was my second try. At first I declared them as "None" instead of global.

Comment: Inside `anotherMethod()` you can still access `request.args(...)`

Comment: @noslenkwah no, I can't :) I have edited to see my 2 tries which didn't worked

Comment: Then there is important code missing. As written the [request context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/) should be available to `anotherMethod()` when it's called inside `setup(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use global vars. `request.args.get()` defaults to string, so no need for that.  Try this to diagnose:

```
@app.route("/set", methods=["GET","POST"])
def setup():

    auth     = request.args.get("auth")
    username = request.args.get("username")
    password = request.args.get("password")
    index    = request.args.get("index")
    authType = request.args.get("type", "no type arg sent")
    rotation = request.args.get("rotation")
    
    print(authType)
    return anotherMethod(authType)

def anotherMethod(authType=None):
    print(f"authType is {authType} inside anotherMethod()")
    return "success"
```

**EDIT:**

If you insist on using globals. you need to declare them inside the function (if you want to chage them there):

```
auth = username = password = index = authType = rotation = None

@app.route("/set", methods=["GET","POST"])
def setup():

    global auth, username, password, index, authType, rotation

    auth     = request.args.get("auth")
    username = request.args.get("username")
    password = request.args.get("password")
    index    = request.args.get("index")
    authType = request.args.get("type", "no type arg sent")
    rotation = request.args.get("rotation")
    
    print(authType)
    return anotherMethod()

def anotherMethod():
    print(f"authType is {authType} inside anotherMethod()")
    return "success"
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION:**

Not sure why you don't want to pass the values as method variables, but this may fit your desire. nested functions:

```
@app.route("/set", methods=["GET","POST"])
def setup():

    auth     = request.args.get("auth")
    username = request.args.get("username")
    password = request.args.get("password")
    index    = request.args.get("index")
    authType = request.args.get("type", "no type arg sent")
    rotation = request.args.get("rotation")
    
    print(authType)

    def anotherMethod():
        print(f"authType is {authType} inside anotherMethod()")
        return "success"

    print(anotherMethod())
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I don't want to make them necessarily global, I just need them in other methods

Comment: well, I have mentioned in my question that I don't want to pass them as method variable because I know how to do that. I don't what them to be None, I said that instead to declaring them global variables, my first try was to set them as "None" 
This is a flask and I get my variables with API calls.
I don't want to pass them as method variables because I have 4 methods using all the variables mentioned above "auth,username, etc.." and I was looking for a way to be able to work with all of them once I get them from POST API call

Comment: So, your API will make a call to `/set`, then make another call to some other URI.  That is not within the same session, so the globals will be lost. You should send as method vars to all 4 functions.

Comment: No, just an api call to ser with requested args

Comment: See edited answer.  If you insist on using globals, you need to declare inside function.

Comment: I don’t insist declaring them as globals. I was just looking for a way to be able to use them in more methods instead in just one that is set()

Comment: Maybe the third way above is what you want?

Comment: thank you. Proabably I’ll go for passing variables in methods if there isn’t another viable solution